# Downloading webapp folder from cloudfroundry v2 (pivotal)

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, cloud-foundry

I was working on a spring based app and i fried my system , and hence lost the app source code. Is there anyway to download the application folder (WAR) in v2 of cloudfoundry?

I know there is a way to download the WAR folder in v1 - **https://gist.github.com/danhigham/4705713** but i cant figure out a way in v2.

I can view a file contents by using (cant download it)-

> cf file app-name path

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can download your application code in v2 of Cloud Foundry (CF).  It is allowed via REST API to CF (see [this line in cloud controller](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cloud_controller_ng/blob/cef9b97fc77e17d396b0c13ec3393cd56eac7a69/app/controllers/core/app_bits_controller.rb#L54)). Good explanation how to use it (may be outdated) is [here](http://corneliadavis.com/blog/2013/03/06/using-the-cloud-controller-rest-interface/). This are good news.

Bad news are that currently cf tool (ruby client to v2) does not support this operation yet. But you still have a few options:

- Use any REST client (e.g. browser's plugin, there are plenty of those) to perform this request manually.
- Improve cf client (or any other library, for example [.NET client lib to CF v2](https://github.com/denisroschinenko/vcap-client-v2), it worked for me) to support download operation. This is a harder way, but you could then contribute your work to the community (as an author of an example for v1 that you've provided did).

I've used the first approach:

- First, I targeted CF server (https://api.run.pivotal.io in my case) and logined to it using [ruby cf client](http://docs.cloudfoundry.com/docs/using/managing-apps/cf/).
- Then I've opened `.cf\tokens.yml` file in my user's directory and copied `:token:` corresponding to my target (further I was adding the value of this token as an `Authosization` header to every request I've done using REST client).
- Then, using REST client I've got the list of apps by issuing a `GET` request to a https://api.run.pivotal.io/v2/apps URl. From its response I've discovered the GUID of the app I'm interested in (say, 3F2504E0-4F89-11D3-9A0C-0305E82C3301).
- And, finally, I've issued `GET` request to https://api.run.pivotal.io//v2/apps/3F2504E0-4F89-11D3-9A0C-0305E82C3301/download . It gave me an HTTP/1.1 302 Found redirect and by opening the URL provided in `Location` header of the response in browser I've downloaded  my app's archive.

Comment: can you make a tool to do that :) I need to download a war file deployed there.

Comment: Actually there is no need in such a tool(it wold be too specific, unless integrated in any client library). It is quite easy to perform 4 steps that I've mentioned with the help of any REST client, say [this](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo) or [this](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm) chrome extensions. And it would take no more than 5-10 minutes